# Function return System.IO.MemoryStream?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I trying to display image in picture box. The application have two part.
First part is windows application, and second part is web service (asmx).

This is the code for windows application:

```
Public Sub PrikazSlike()
             Dim p As localhost.Service1 = New localhost.Service1()
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(p.PictureShow()) 
End Sub
```

And this is the code for web service:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Service1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function PictureShow() As System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim stream1 As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim data As Byte() = client.DownloadData("http://www.psp-themes.net/.../assassins%20creed%203.jpg")
        client.Dispose()
        stream1.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        Return stream1
    End Function
End Class
```

The problem is  that function in web service does  not return  System.IO.MemoryStream data type so I getting error message can not convert:
Error    1    Value of type 'WindowsApplication1.localhost.MemoryStream' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.Stream'.

How I can resolve this?

Many thanks!

**Update** (originally posted as an 'answer')

This is the update code for web service:

```
   <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function PrikazSlike() As Byte
        Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()
        'Dim data As Byte

        Dim data As Byte() = client.DownloadData("http://www.psp-themes.net/.../assassins%20creed%203.jpg")
        Dim stream1 As New System.IO.MemoryStream(data)
        client.Dispose()
        stream1.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        Return Convert.ToByte(stream1)
    End Function
End Class
```

This is the windows application code:

```
Public Sub Show.Picture()
         Dim p As localhost.Service1 = New localhost.Service1()
         PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(p.PictureShow()) 
         End Sub
```

Now I getting error:

Error   1   Value of type 'Byte' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.Stream'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that your method returns the type `WindowsApplication1.localhost.MemoryStream` and not a `System.IO.MemoryStream`.

I suspect that your web service is set up to return a `MemoryStream` object. Try to change it to return a `byte[`] array instead. On your receiving side retrieve the byte array and create a `System.IO.MemoryStream` from that array.

Comment: Ok. I changed web service to return byte:

  <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function PrikazSlike() As Byte
        Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim stream1 As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim data As Byte() = client.DownloadData("http://www.psp-themes.net/.../assassins%20creed%203.jpg")
        client.Dispose()
        stream1.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        Return Convert.ToByte(stream1)
    End Function
End Class

But now how i can convert bytes to System.IO.MemoryStream in windows application.

Comment: Use the contstructor for MemoryStream that takes a byte array. Dim stream1 As New System.IO.MemoryStream(data)

Comment: Now I am getting in windows application error:
Error 1 Value of type 'Byte' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.Stream'.

Comment: Can you update your example code? It probably is the return value of one of your methods that is wrong. You return a Byte instead of a MemoryStream.

Comment: web service code:

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function ShowPicture() As Byte
        Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()
        'Dim data As Byte

   Dim data As Byte() = client.DownloadData("http://www.psp-themes.net/.../assassins%20creed%203.jpg")
   Dim stream1 As New System.IO.MemoryStream(data)
   client.Dispose()
 stream1.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
Return Convert.ToByte(stream1)
    End Function
End Class

windows applicartion code:
Public Sub PrikazSlike()
Dim p As localhost.Service1 = New localhost.Service1()
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(p.PictureShow()) 
End Sub

Comment: Your ShowPicture method returns a sigle byte instead of a byte array. Change it to Public Function ShowPicture() As Byte().

Comment: I change this:
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function PrikazSlike() As Byte()
        Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()
        'Dim data As Byte

        Dim data As Byte() = client.DownloadData("http://www.psp-themes.net/.../assassins%20creed%203.jpg")
        Dim stream1 As New System.IO.MemoryStream(data)
        client.Dispose()
        stream1.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        Return Convert.ToByte(stream1)
    End Function
End Class


Now I getting error:
Error 1 Value of type 'Byte' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte'

Comment: Did you update your web reference? Also, it would be easier to read your code if you update it in your question. Somewhere you return a byte instead of a byte array and that causes your compile error.

Answer (score 6):

Try to return byte array instead of Stream.

Answer (score 0):

The MemoryStream resides on the server and can't be serialized to the client.

You should return a bytearray from your webservice then transform this to a image.